# Memory error In instantiating the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a list **A** of a 50,000 elements and each element is an array of shape (102400)

I tried instantiating an array **B**.

```
     B=numpy.array(A)
```

But this throws an exception MemoryError.I know that the memory and size is very huge?But is there a way to avoid this MemoryError with ndarrays in numpy ??

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: What do you intend to do with this big array?  Even if you manage to create it, you may not be able to do anything meaningful with it.  During calculations `numpy` makes temporary buffers, and may leave one or more copies in memory.  Some things are just too big.

Comment: Are those elements really arrays - if so what dtype?  Or are they lists as well?  Can you make the array with a subset of `A`?

Comment: Can you load the data to B directly, without creating `list` A?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are int64 (the default numpy type). Each occupies 8 bytes, then:
The dimensions by the amount of bytes that occupy each one:

```
50000 * 102400 * 8 = 40960000000
```

In gigabytes

```
50000 * 102400 * 8 / 1024**3 = 38.14697265625 Gb
```

Comment: So the solution is to buy more memory. ;)

Comment: Maybe the solution is to do it by chunks (that you enter into memory), or change the type: if you know they are positive, use uint. If it does, use int32 or int16.

Comment: Even with int8 it will be more then 4Gb, and A itself is occupying a lot of memory.

Comment: Working with big things is not easy! Moving from 40 Gb to 4 Gb is something. If you also do it for bits (200 Mb for example) you have it solved.

Comment: I agree. What I mean is given no other details from the OP the only piece of advice is "buy more memory"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could avoid copying the arrays with something like:

```
B = np.empty(len(A), dtype=object)
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    B[i] = a
```

This would allow to create a ndarray of dtype `object` whose elements would be the original elements of `A`. You could then perform *some* array operations on it.

But I am not sure you have something to win in going this way.